# Preflight OPTIONS request to SOAP service does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, cxf, cors

*What I want to do*: Call a cross-domain SOAP-Service from JavaScript using jQuery with the jQuery Soap plugin (by Remy Blom). (that is, I call `$.soap();` in JavaScript)

*What I did*: CORS Setting on the server side (CXF) are working (using the `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter`), so the following is present in the answer:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    http://localhost:8082
Content-Type                    application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
```

*What is missing*: Firefox and Chrome send preflight `OPTIONS` requests prior to the `POST` request for the SOAP call. Obviously SOAP does not allow the `OPTIONS` verb.

It does not work with SoapUI (5.0) as well as CXF (2.7.7). It is even stated in a comment in `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor` line 130ff:

```
/*
 * Reject OPTIONS, and any other noise that is not allowed in SOAP.
 */
```

So, my question is: How can I modify my SOAP servcie implementation (using CXF), such that the `OPTIONS` request returns successfully?

Comment: If I understood right; then, you just need to annotate your WebService class with @OPTIONS. See: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-cors.html

Comment: @YoriKusanagi This describes how to solve this for a REST-service not for a SOAP-service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if it's a little bit late, I had the same problem recently and maybe it will help future travelers.

In the case of an `OPTIONS` request you may not continue with the FilterChain. 
I created a simple CORSFilter, which looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*

public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));

        if (!req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

And I added the following to my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```